# Django Ajax - Dajaxice.myapp is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to implement Ajax functionality into my website. This seems to be a moderately common problem, but all solutions to it I've found online have been simple, like forgetting something in the tutorial. The error message appears in the JavaScript console.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

My actions:

I used `pip install django_dajaxice` for install

I copy-pasted the `settings.py` and `urls.py` code in the tutorial into my own:

```
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # AJAX
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

and

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ( ... ) # Exact copy paste from tutorial

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ( ... ) # Exact copy paste from tutorial

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ( ... ) # Exact copy paste from tutorial
```

I included the template tags in my `base.html`, the actual html file inherits from that

Then Quickstart: http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

I created content/ajax.py (content is my app). Code inside is simple:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from content import models
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def fav(request):
    dajax = Dajax()
    return dajax.json()
```

Finally, the JS and HTML code which instantiates the AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}dajaxice/dajaxice.core.js"></script>
function js_callback(data) {
    Dajax.process(data);
    alert(data.message);
}

<a onClick="Dajaxice.content.fav(js_callback);">Favorite</a>
```

Comment: Solved: I need to include a return false; after the onClick call to the JS function. That wasn't included in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `collectstatic` again to regenerate `dajaxice.core.js`.
And maybe you should remove the static files has been collected before.